Keep his commandments?

This is how we know that we know him: if we keep his commandments. 4 One who says, “I know him,” and doesn’t keep his commandments, is a liar, and the truth isn’t in him. 5 But God’s love has most certainly been perfected in whoever keeps his word. This is how we know that we are in him: 6 he who says he remains in him ought himself also to walk just like he walked. (1 John 2:3-6)

Does this mean that there are commandments that Christians must keep? What are those commandments? What are some examples of things that Christians must do? (Please provide references.)

Brothers, I write no new commandment to you, but an old commandment which you had from the beginning. The old commandment is the word which you heard from the beginning. 8 Again, I write a new commandment to you, which is true in him and in you, because the darkness is passing away and the true light already shines. (1 John 2:7-8)

Is the old commandment the Torah? That is what the Jews had from the beginning. Is John encouraging people to follow the Torah?
What does he mean when he says that he is not writing a new commandment but he is writing a new commandment?

The world is passing away with its lusts, but he who does God’s will remains forever. (1 John 2:17)

Did God express His will in the Tanakh? Is John talking about doing God's will as expressed in the Tanakh?

What commandments?  See https://www.abc.net.au/reslib/201407/r1308729_17984331.pdf  and  https://www.cai.org/bible-studies/1050-new-testament-commands  and  https://www.facebook.com/notes/the-real-truth-movement/the-1050-new-testament-commandmentslaws/690826194404882/  and  http://www.wholebible.com/NT_commandments.htm  and  http://www.biblicalresearchreports.com/gods-commands-in-the-new-testament/

Indeed, counted this way, the NT has more divine commandments than the OT by far!!

And this is his commandment, That we should believe on the name of his Son Jesus Christ, and love one another, as he gave us commandment. 1 John 3:23. KJV.

@Dottard This is fascinating. Thank you for posting. Does any large denomination teach that Christians have to follow all these laws? Which one? What about the "old commandment" from 1 John 2:7?

@NigelJ What about the "old commandment" that John also preaches?

This is very controversial, only because people will not accept what Jesus and the NT clearly say.  Paul sums this up well when he says (Eph 2:8-10), 8 For it is by grace you have been saved through faith, and this not from yourselves; it is the gift of God, 9 not by works, so that no one can boast. 10 For we are God’s workmanship, created in Christ Jesus to do good works, which God prepared in advance as our way of life.

Most protestant churches used to preach this but many have now modified their position because they confuse the ROOT of salvation (the grace and love of Christ) with the FRUIT of salvation (good works according to Eph 2:10).  Indeed, Jesus actually says this in John 15:14 - "If you love Me, you will keep My commandments."  The Grammar here is future indicative active meaning that when we love Christ, keeping His commandments with be a stated fact.

You've asked 9 different questions here; the expected limit is 1.
To answer the Title question, yes, John is saying that Christians should keep God's commandments (as given in the Torah, and with the spiritual understanding given by Jesus).
There is no reason to think that John's references to "commandments" could mean anything else, as shown by his other uses of this term:

John 14:15 — If ye love me, keep my commandments.
John 14:21 — He that hath my commandments, and keepeth them, he it is that loveth me: and he that loveth me shall be loved of my Father, and I will love him, and will manifest myself to him.
John 15:10 — If ye keep my commandments, ye shall abide in my love; even as I have kept my Father's commandments, and abide in his love.
1 John 3:22 — And whatsoever we ask, we receive of him, because we keep his commandments, and do those things that are pleasing in his sight.
1 John 3:24 — And he that keepeth his commandments dwelleth in him, and he in him. And hereby we know that he abideth in us, by the Spirit which he hath given us.
1 John 5:2 — By this we know that we love the children of God, when we love God, and keep his commandments.
1 John 5:3 — For this is the love of God, that we keep his commandments: and his commandments are not grievous.
2 John 1:6 — And this is love, that we walk after his commandments. This is the commandment, That, as ye have heard from the beginning, ye should walk in it.
Revelation 12:17 — And the dragon was wroth with the woman, and went to make war with the remnant of her seed, which keep the commandments of God, and have the testimony of Jesus Christ.
Revelation 14:12 — Here is the patience of the saints: here are they that keep the commandments of God, and the faith of Jesus.
Revelation 22:14 — Blessed are they that do his commandments, that they may have right to the tree of life, and may enter in through the gates into the city.

and as confirmed by Jesus's statement in Matthew 5 (NLT):

17 “Don’t misunderstand why I have come. I did not come to abolish the law of Moses or the writings of the prophets. No, I came to accomplish their purpose.
18 I tell you the truth, until heaven and earth disappear, not even the smallest detail of God’s law will disappear until its purpose is achieved.
19 So if you ignore the least commandment and teach others to do the same, you will be called the least in the Kingdom of Heaven. But anyone who obeys God’s laws and teaches them will be called great in the Kingdom of Heaven.

The Torah gives 3 major types of commandments:

Civil (for running the nation of Israel).
Levitical (for running the priesthood).
General (for running one's life).

The first group went away with the conquest of Israel by the Roman Empire.
The second became of no effect with the destruction of the Temple and the Priesthood in year 70.
The third is still in effect for all mankind.

Thank you for your thorough response. I agree with your reading - John is telling people to keep the commandments of the Torah. Followup questions: 1) The division into the 3 types of commandments - is that anywhere in the Bible? 2) Num. 15:38 tells people to wear special fringes on their clothes. Using your classification, that's a "General" commandment. Should Christians follow it?

@DavidGilford, some things aren't as obvious as one would like. It's further complicated by some rules being part of specific covenants. It took the Apostles themselves a while to realize that some requirements, such as circumcision, are part of the covenant between God and Abraham and not a general requirement for all Christians.

+1. You could add also Jesus' words: "to enter into life, keep the commandments".

@NepheshRoi. Yes, and others.  But I limited the selection to what John himself reported about commandments, to show that he consistently uses the term to refer to God's commandments, with not even a hint that he meant anything else by it.

"The Torah gives 3 major types of commandments" - source for that?

@AviAvraham, I guess "contains" would have been a better word than "gives".¶ Most of them can be easily separated though: "A priest shall …" is clearly Levitical, while specific offenses with attached compensation rules are clearly Civil. If something is "an abomination unto the Lord", it is a general truth, not only for Israel.

@Ray Butterworth, Can I wear clothing made of blended fabrics such as cotton and polyester? Our planters contain both tomatoes and peppers--is that wrong?  Noah made offerings on an altar.  We have a lot of doves and quail that visit our yard. I suppose I could catch some of them, but quite honestly I'd find it hard to tear them apart with my bare hands and then burn them on a pile of uncut stone in front of my house as an offering. What do you think? Or maybe do only the Ten Commandments apply? What about the letter from the apostles and elders to the gentile believers in Acts 15:28-29?

@Dieter, for Acts 15:28–29, see my answer to Were there implicit laws not referenced in the Acts 15 letter to gentile believers? - Christianity Stack Exchange.

Okay, I read your apologetic on why it would be practical not to apply all of the laws of Torah to gentile converts, but I still don't know the answers to my previous questions. Let me also add the question of why Paul considered Torah as a guardian until Christ came as he wrote in Galatians 3. I think the literal Greek is instructive:https://biblehub.com/interlinear/galatians/3.htm

@Dieter, Bible Hub's Leviticus 19:19 Commentaries seem to agree that these laws were related to the Levitical services or to the running of the nation of Israel, and not general laws for all mankind. The animal sacrifices were physical symbols of Jesus's sacrifice and are now superseded by the real thing.

@Dieter, Galatians 3:12 says "And the law is not of faith: but, The man that doeth them shall live in them.". I think this is pointing out that under Judaism, only one's physical actions count (thoughts do not become evil until one acts upon them). But under the Christian Covenant, it is not one's actions but one's thoughts that truly count. An Israelite that hates but does nothing about it has not sinned (according to their Covenant), but a Christian that hates has sinned even without acting upon those feelings. The physical interpretation of the law gave rules for physically avoiding sin.

I understand what you're saying and this is my last comment. Do I need to buy clothes that aren't made with blended fabric, and do I need to tear out the pepper plants that I planted together with my tomatoes?

@Dieter, I'd say no, but I'm not someone that should be offering pastoral advice. ¶ An even better example would be Three Sisters (agriculture), where three different but complementary plants are grown together.

Love, love, love

“So now faith, hope, and love abide, these three; but the greatest
of these is LOVE” (1 Cor 13:13).

In fact, wise men say that the crux of the entire Bible is “Love”.
But what is love?

“And this is love, that we should walk according to His
commandments” (2 John 1:6).


“For this is the love of God, that we keep His commandments; and His
commandments are not heavy” (1 John 5:3).

Jesus Christ said:

“If you love Me, keep My commandments” (John 14:15).


“If you keep My commandments you will continue in My love, as I have
kept My Father's commandments and continue in His love” (John 15:10).

[Are these two different sets of commandments?; one set of the Father and a different set of the Son?
No. Jesus said, “This is true, because I have not spoken on my own authority, but the Father who sent me has commanded me what I must say and speak” (John 12:49). So these are the same set]
Jesus also said:

“But if you desire to enter into life, keep the commandments” (Mat
19:17).

Which commandments?
Jesus pinpoints the Ten Commandments in verses 18 and 19. These are the Father’s Commandments. These are Jesus’ own commandments.
This is the Biblical definition of Godly love. The world misunderstands love as a mere feeling, an infatuation or worse as lust that is self-centered.
So, “agape” or true love is keeping the Commandments of God with full heart.
Paul said:

“love one another. For the one who loves another has fulfilled the
Law……... Therefore, love is the fulfillment of the Law” (Rom 13:
8, 10).

So, God = love = keeping the commandments.
One Love Two
This love can be divided into 2 sections:
1)  Love towards God and 2) love towards fellow human beings who are truly in the image and likeness of God. [That is why Jesus said if you do good to a least brother you do it to Jesus]

“Teacher, which is the great commandment in the Law? And Jesus said to
him, "You shall love the Lord your God with all your heart, and with
all your soul, and with all your mind." This is the first and
great commandment. And the second is like it: "You shall love your
neighbor as yourself." On these two commandments all the Law and the
Prophets hang” (Mat 22:36-40).

Jesus was quoting from Deuteronomy and Leviticus.
Love towards God is divided into 4 commandments. These are the first 4 of the Ten Commandments.
Love towards man is divided into 6 commandments. These are the next 6 of the Ten Commandments.
If there is any doubt about this, Apostle Paul is more than happy to clarify:

“For, "Do not commit adultery," "do not murder," "do not steal," do
not bear false witness, "do not lust," and if there is any other
commandment, in this word it is SUMMED UP, in the words, "You
shall love your neighbor as yourself." (Rom 13:9).

Jesus Modifies the 2nd Law
Lord Jesus wields His authority to modify the second greatest commandment. Earlier, it was “love your neighbor as yourself”
But Jesus modifies it slightly yet significantly:

“I give a new commandment to you, that you should love one another;
according as I loved you, you should also love one another” (John
13:34).

Yes, now we are not to love our brothers as we love ourselves. But we are to love others as Jesus has loved us; a truly sacrificial love (I know it is easy to say than do).
A False Teaching
The traditional Christian world thinks that the Jews were keeping the Ten Commandments of God yet they fell short of God’s glory. It believes falsely that Apostle Paul accused the Jews as “legalists”!
Truth cannot be farther.
Jesus Christ Himself testified that the Jews set aside God’s commandments in order to follow the additional traditions of their forefathers.

“and in vain they worship Me, teaching as doctrines the
commandments of men." For forsaking the commandment of God, you hold the tradition of men: ……….And He said to them, Well do
you to set aside the commandment of God so that you may keep
your tradition? For Moses said, "Honor your father and your
mother;" and, "The one speaking evil of father or mother, let him
expire by death." But you say, If a man says to his father or mother,
Corban, (which is, A gift!) whatever you may profit by me. And you no
longer allow him to do anything for his father or mother, making the
Word of God of no effect by your tradition which you delivered. And
many such like things you do (Mark 7:7-13).

I think Jesus cannot be plainer and more direct than this. So no more comments from me.
Law of Righteousness
The Ten Commandments are called the Law of Righteousness.
Paul says that the Jews NEVER reached at it:

“but Israel following after a Law of righteousness did not
arrive at a Law of righteousness” (Rom 9:31).

The Ten Commandments, the Law of righteousness, is projected as a target to achieve by Paul.
The problem with the Jews is that they tried (but failed) to achieve it by means of the “Works of Law (the animal sacrifices)” (verse 32).
It has become clear that the Ten Commandments are a goal and the Works of Law are a means the Jews used to reach there.
They “stumbled at” the Messiah’s eternal and once for all perfect Sacrifice (verses 32-33) . Instead of accepting the Christ’s perfect sacrifice “through faith” they still wanted to depend on the “foods and drinks, and various washings, and fleshly ordinances (animal sacrifices)” (Heb 9:10).
So the Jews never kept the Law of righteousness, the Ten Commandments. They never could.
In fact no one ever could without the Holy Spirit (Rom 8:7) as the Ten Commandments are "spiritual" (Rom 7:14) "holy", "righteous" and "good" (verse 12) which a "mere human" (without the Holy Spirit) cannot follow.
Conclusion

“Circumcision (works of law) is nothing, and uncircumcision is
nothing, but obeying God's commandments is everything” (1 Cor
7:19).

This is addressed to the New Testament Christians by Paul. So the Ten Commandments are still in force. Jesus did not nail them on the cross.

You say Jesus did not nail the Ten Commandments on the cross. If so, then what was nailed to the cross? Of God it is said he has forgiven Christians all their trespasses, "blotting out the handwriting of ordinances that was against us, which was contrary to us, and took it out of the way, nailing it to the cross." Col.2:14. The Ten Commandments were the ordinances of God, hand-written by his own finger. They are against every human, for no human can keep them. They expose just how sinful we are, as Jesus said to even think lust, or murder, was to break those laws, is that not so?

“but I see another law in my members having warred against the law of my mind, and taking me captive by the law of sin being in my members” (Rom 7:23). Anne, of the 2, which one Jesus could have nailed to the cross? It is really horrible to imagine that Jesus nailed the “law of mind” (the 10 Commandments which God prophesied through Jeremiah 31:33 that He will write in the mind in the 2nd Covenant) on the cross and left intact the “law of sin” in the flesh!

If Jesus had nailed the law of God on the cross, why does Paul, after several years, say, “But we establish Law” (Rom 3:31) and “So then I myself with the mind truly serve the Law of God” (Rom 7:25)?

God nailed the hand-written document that is against us to the cross, taking it out of the way, as all the Law of God does is condemn us as sinners. It does not bring life or peace. Christ dealt with sin at the cross. Rom.3:31, Paul was exposing the false charge of antinomianism; Christians are not against (anti) law (nomia). They are law-abiding but they must never go back to the Law, for Christ died to set us free from its condemnation! To tack on the Law to the Gospel is to corrupt it and make it of no effect. Yet we still love the Law of God even though it’s served its purpose: it led us

to Christ. In Rom.7:25 Paul despaired that all the Law did (when he tried to keep it) was expose his evil-doing due to sin being in him. But having been “delivered from the body of this death” by faith in Christ having dealt with sin at the cross, he loved his new life in Christ. The flesh serves the law of sin. New life in Christ is freedom to obey God with a new mind that is now “the mind of Christ”. Life and peace indwell those born again, replacing death and striving. Bondage to sin is broken; we’re free in Christ to serve willingly and obey Christ’s commands. The Spirit leads, not laws.

“Christians are not against (anti) law (nomia). They are law-abiding” – Anne. Exactly! Then where is the problem? This is what I am also stating, that Christians should be law-abiding. But they cannot abide by the Law which is abolished by having nailed on the cross!

“God nailed the hand-written document that is against us to the cross” – Anne. What is against us is “another law in our members” (Rom 7:23). It is not the “spiritual” (Rom 7:14), “holy”, “righteous”, and “good” Law(Rom 7:12). The “spiritual” among you (Gal 6:1) will abide by the spiritual Law. “It does not bring life or peace” – Anne. “For the Law of the Spirit of life in Christ Jesus set me free from the law of sin and of death” (Rom 8:2). See, there is a Law of spiritual life!

“Christ dealt with sin at the cross” – Anne. Exactly. Jesus abolished the debt of sin (the law of sin in our members). He will never abolish the good, righteous spiritual Law of His Father. “To tack on the Law to the Gospel is to corrupt it and make it of no effect” – Anne. Yet Paul connects Law with the Gospel: “And I was alive apart from Law once, but the commandment came (along with the Gospel!), and sin came alive, and I died” (Rom 7:9).

Are we writing at cross-purposes? ‘Law’ is the Mosaic Law that only condemned Paul, but then was removed at the cross. My objections are against those who say “The Law is the rule of life for Christians.” They tack on legalism to the Gospel. Faith is the rule of life for Christians. Agreed?

Frankly, I see a contradiction in your statements. On one hand you say that the Christians are not antinomians and are law-abiding. On the other, in the same breath, you say Jesus abolished the Law by nailing it on the cross. Then if the Law is no longer, how can they be law-abiding?! It doesn’t make good sense to me. If by Law, you mean the 10C, then it is not Mosaic because Moses never wrote them. First God thundered them down to the people directly. Then, twice, God Himself wrote them down and gave to Moses who simply copied.

Again, the 10C are the rule of life for the true Christians (Mat 22:37-40) as otherwise they would be murderers, adulterers, liars, polytheists etc and Jesus’ sacrifice would be null and void! Moreover, you seem to be mixing up 10C (which are spiritual, holy, righteous and good) with “legalism”. Jesus Himself testified that the Jews never tried to keep the 10C (Mark 7:7-13). What they tried as “legalism” was to stick to their “additional” traditions and works of law like circumcision and animal sacrifices.

“Faith is the rule of life for Christians. Agreed?” – Anne. NO! Paul says point blank: “And now faith, hope, and love, these three things remain; but the greatest of these is love” (1 Cor 13:13). So, love is the rule of life for Christians. But what is love? “For this is the love of God, that we keep His commandments; and His commandments are not heavy” (1 John 5:3). “Then is the Law annulled through faith? Let it not be! But we establish Law” (Rom 3:31).

Jesus gave his disciples a number of new commandments, which you can search for online and in the biblegateway website. For example

A new commandment I give to you, that you love one another: just as I
have loved you, you also are to love one another. - John 13:34 ESV

Let me also point out that Jesus taught that spiritual cleansing was the responsibility of the Father toward those who were abiding/living their lives in Christ Jesus. This is the point of the "I am the vine, you are the branches" lesson that Jesus taught in John 15. What this meant was that his disciples would not need to be concerned with ritual purity, but rather with producing fruit (such as the fruit of the Spirit) in their lives.

Let's start from the "old commandment" that John is talking about. Is he telling Christians to keep the Torah?

@David Gilford, John's teachings included 1. “Repent, for the kingdom of heaven is at hand.” 2. He told the common people, “The one who has two tunics is to share with the one who has none; and the one who has food is to do likewise.” 3. He told tax collectors: “Collect no more than what you have been ordered to.” 4. He told soldiers: “Do not extort money from anyone, nor harass anyone, and be content with your wages.” 5. He told religious leaders: “You brood of vipers, who warned you to flee from the wrath to come? Therefore, bear fruit in keeping with repentance . . .” Not 613 laws of Torah.

@Dieter. Perhaps not 613, but more than a dozen of them:
2 ⇒ 239–251 (charity for the poor),
and 3–4 ⇒ 476–477 (coveting/extortion),
and 1,5 ⇒ 75 (repentance).
— The 613 Commandments (Mitzvot) - Chabad.org.

@Ray Butterworth, Yes, and also notice the qualitative difference between the majority of the 613 laws in Torah with any of the dozens of commandments of Jesus. Note that Jesus elaborated (aka creating "fences") with regards to Torah in critical commentary on the legalistic misapplication of the Pharisees. For example Jesus told them that even looking at a woman with lust or hating your brother was a violation of Torah. This critic applies to all legalists. To his disciples, his commandments were that they should serve one another, be forgiving, pray for their enemies, etc.

Up voted. Dieter, the commandment you quoted is in fact an old commandment but new in form. The old said to love our neighbor as ourselves. But now Jesus says to love one another as He loved us. And how did He love us? By dying for us!

Context is clear. John was addressing Christians to have confidence in Christ, their "advocate with the Father, Jesus Christ the righteous" - verse 1. He immediately goes on to say that it is the commandments of Jesus that Christians are to keep.
Now, if John had wanted to say that it is the commandments of the Torah - the O.T. Law - that Christians are to keep, he would simply have said so. Would he not? Why did John not refer to the Old Testament Law of Moses? Well, anyone who has studied his gospel knows why not. Consider what he reported Jesus as saying:

"If a man love me, he will keep my words: and my Father will love him,
and we will come unto him, and make our abode with him. He that loveth
me not keepeth not my sayings: and the word which ye hear is not mine,
but the Father's which sent me." John 14:23-24 K.J.V.

Christians are to know the sayings of Jesus their Saviour. Where are his sayings and commands to be found? In the Christian Greek Scriptures. Did Jesus ever say that his followers must continue to follow the Mosaic Law? No. Nowhere.
What John did record Jesus as saying to those who asked him what they had to do to "work the works of God" was:

"This is the work of God, that ye believe on him whom he hath sent."
John 6:28-29 K.J.V.

With those foundational truths in place, read all the words of Jesus and discover what his commands are. The question, as it stands, is far too vast in its scope to deal with here. It is not a topic that biblical Hermeneutics is for, but for a specific text (or two, if directly related.) I am sticking to the text in 1 John chapter 2. Context is clear. And the writer of that chapter wrote equally clear truths on the matter in his gospel.
EDIT due to extended comments – to clear up any misunderstanding. I never said “Jesus abolished the law by nailing it to the cross.” I quoted Col.2:14 where God blotted out the handwriting of ordinances that was against us [and his own finger wrote the 10 commandments]. God knew that they were all contrary to us (for nobody can keep them) yet they serve the purpose to lead us to Christ. Thus, when Christ went to the cross for God to righteously deal with sin, God effectively nailed them to the cross. Jesus fulfilled the law. God then nailed them to the cross.
If “the 10 commandments are the rule of life for the true Christian”, then we are all doomed because not even Spirit-filled Christians can keep them, Jesus exposing how even thinking lustful or hateful thoughts means we’ve broken them. All Spirit-filled Christians show agape love to God, family, neighbours, friends, strangers, even those who hate and persecute them. Not because any law tells us, but because the love of God, in Christ, has transformed us by grace. Faith is the key to all of this, which is a gift from God. Hence (the bottom line): faith is the rule of life for all Christians. As the scripture says, “All that is not of faith is sin.” Romans 14:23. Christians are no longer murderers, adulterers, liars, polytheists or in any way act as antinomians. They have been transformed by grace and live to please and obey God and Christ, not out of fear of breaking any laws, but due to love of God and Christ.
